# Visual Studio Asking for Volumes Folder

Tags: visual-studio-mac

[Image shows the folder and the folder path in the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QL1T.png)

I just got a new MacBook and have installed the MacOS version of Visual Studio: Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac. I previously had a solution in the Windows version that worked fine. I am working from a USB stick due to this being a project for school. When I try to open the solution on my MacBook there is an error, where it can't find a Volumes folder, that it thinks the USB directory should be in, and this does not make sense to me. Here is the error message that I am receiving:

```
Error while trying to load the project '/Volumes/OWENRACCANI/Visual Studio 2015/WebSites/WebSite4': File not found: /Volumes/OWENRACCANI/Visual Studio 2015/WebSites/WebSite4
```

Where OWENRACCANI is the name of my USB stick, and Website4 is the name of my project. I can't find any folder named Volumes on my laptop or on the USB and I have no clue what is happening.
Any solutions are helpful and will be tried.
Thank you.

Comment: `/Volumes/OWENRACCANI` **is** the USB stick.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok. the file is located in the exact location of the path it says so do you have any idea why it still isn't working. I''l try to include a screenshot  of that path location.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've added the image now.